# MVC Postal conflicting with _viewstart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, postal

My app is producing the error

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

For some reason  Postal is giving an error with the layouts in the root _ViewStart.cshtml specifically the first if statement which is shown below.

**_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
    if (this.User.IsInRole("Admin") || !this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
else if (this.User.IsInRole("Territorial Strategic Planning Coordinator") || this.User.IsInRole("Programme Secretary") || this.User.IsInRole("IT") || !this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLevel1.cshtml";
}  
else if (this.User.IsInRole("Divison Commander") || !this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLevel2.cshtml";
}
else if (this.User.IsInRole("Corps Officer") || this.User.IsInRole("Centre Admin") || !this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLevel3.cshtml";
}
```

The code I'm using within my controller is :

```
 dynamic email = new Email("GoalNotification");
                email.ResponseID = goal.ResponseID;
                email.User = user.UserName;
                email.To = user.Email;
                email.Send();
```

and the Postal View is :
**GoalNotification.cshtml**

```
To: @ViewBag.To
Subject: Goal Notification for Response : @ViewBag.ResponseID

<div>

    <p style="font-size:large; font-weight:bold">
        Dear @ViewBag.User
    </p>
    <p>
        This is a system generated notification to notify you that one or more of your goals need attention.
    </p>
    <p>
        Please revise and re-submit.
    </p>

    <p>Kind Regards</p>

    <p>TSP</p>
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <p style="font-weight:100"><u>Contact Details</u></p>
    <p>Office Number: </p>
    <p>Email Address: </p>
    <p>Physical Address: </p>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here? and is there any way to fix this?
Its my first time using Postal. Thanks for any help.

Edit: Im only getting this error because MVC Postal seems to be overriding my root _ViewStart. The program runs normal without it.

Postal has an issue when there is more than one layout specified it seems. If i have one set layout it works. Unfortunately I need to have them.

**The Stack Trace :**

```
    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views__ViewStart_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Shahil\Desktop\TSPMVC Backups\2016\28-01-2016\TSP MVC\TSP MVC\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml:3
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +73
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +131
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   Postal.EmailViewRenderer.RenderView(IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ControllerContext controllerContext, ImageEmbedder imageEmbedder) +182
   Postal.EmailViewRenderer.Render(Email email, String viewName) +204
   Postal.EmailService.CreateMailMessage(Email email) +72
   Postal.EmailService.Send(Email email) +65
   Postal.Email.Send() +56
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) +189
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1(CallSite site, T0 arg0) +432
   TSP_MVC.Controllers.GoalsController.AdminEdit(Goal goal) in c:\Users\Shahil\Desktop\TSPMVC Backups\2016\28-01-2016\TSP MVC\TSP MVC\Controllers\GoalsController.cs:195
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9721605
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Did you check `this.User` is NULL or not before accessing any property of that ?

Comment: Yes. User is logged in and has value.